# .show() doesn't work immediately - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button click function like this :

```
   $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();
       console.log("let's show my div");
      $('#mydiv').show();
      //and then doing a lot of front end operations and some ajax calls
   })
```

When I click the submit button, I get the `console.log` message immediately. But `.show()` method works like 7-8 seconds after that. Can you tell me how I can make `.show()` work immediately? Thanks.

EDIT : 
My HTML code looks like this :

```
    <div class="main">
        <form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-forms">
             <div class="first-line">
                <div class="span3 main-row">
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" placeholder="insert your ID"  maxlength="7"  oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"  />

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="first-line">
                <div class="span8 main-row">
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
                    </div>

                </div>
             </div>
   <div id="mydiv" style="display:none">

                    <label>
                        Processing, please wait.
                    </label>

        </div>
        </form>
     </div>
```

Comment: What's happening during those 7-8 seconds? Are there CPU-intensive operations?

Comment: Can you provide HTML code or create a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Mostly trying to validate data coming from user and 4-5 AJAX calls.

Comment: Is any of that CPU intensive? (if so, the answer is easy, else we'll need a [MCVE] I think)

Comment: @CertainPerformance They are not CPU intensive I think. Almost all of them are simple if statements.

Comment: please share your html code, are you set #mydiv to display none?

Comment: @MortezaFathnia Yes.

Comment: any where do you change display?

Comment: @MortezaFathnia Yes. I use `.show` as seen in the question.

Comment: Given what you've said about it, the code you show should just work with no delay. Since you have a delay, the issue is related to code you haven't shown. In order to troubleshoot this, we're going to need to see a working example.

Comment: The JS + HTML posted in the question does not result in the problem you describe. We do indeed need a [MCVE]

Answer (score -1):

This is example of showing the div , you should hide your div with display none not hidden class , if you use hidden class just remove class to show your div

```js
function ShowDiv(){
$("#mydiv").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" style='display:none;'>Hello</div>
<button onclick="ShowDiv()"> ShowMe</button>
```

Comment: please check this link,Are you sure javascript code in end of body element:
http://jsfiddle.net/Luo06943/

Comment: @MortezaFathnia what do you mean?!

Comment: script tag placed before end of body tag.
<body><script></script></body>

Comment: @MortezaFathnia This is not important here ! The problem isn't place of script. In addition when you use code snippet in here and you use jquery it's automatically inserted in your code.

Comment: do you test the link? I don't find out your meant?!